# Small Colum and large table - Should i use FTS or Like

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

At the moment i am using Full text (2008 R2) on small columns like 'Client Name', 'PO Number' and etc ? but i was wondering if it is really worth using FTS on small columns and could use 'Like' for searching.

Table has over 11k rows which is not alot but this table is growing.

If it is better to use 'Like' than do i have to remove columns from the catalog?

What is meant by unstructured text data here?

"In contrast to full-text search, the LIKE Transact-SQL predicate works on character patterns only. Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to query formatted binary data. Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned. "

Comment: Have you tried comparing your full text queries to LIKE queries?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using full text, why change it? LIKE queries may be suitable now but the performance will degrade sharply as your table grows, as stated in the [MSDN article you quoted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx).

> If it is better to use 'Like' than do i have to remove columns from
>   the catalog?

No, the full text catalog has no impact on LIKE queries.

> What is meant by unstructured text data here?

Full text can be used on binary formats that SQL Server supports (imagine searching across Word files stored in SQL) and XML data. LIKE cannot do this.